# Hangfire does not find the app files eventhough it gets heartbeat

Tags: hangfire

The Hangfire does not find, or resolve, the project assembly -all of it- eventhough it gets a heartbeat.

Not sure what is causing this, but the dashboard also shows that the app restarts every three minute which is impossible because we use a loadbalancer on an app that is being used by hundreds of people at the same time. This many cold-starts would mean extremely long loading times which the users would complain about.

This is the error that is shown on the `recurring jobs` tab;

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Recurring job can't be scheduled, see inner exception for details.
 ---> Hangfire.Common.JobLoadException: Could not load the job. See inner exception for the details.
 ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not resolve assembly 'My.Api'.
   at System.TypeNameParser.ResolveAssembly(String asmName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Boolean throwOnError, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.TypeNameParser.ConstructType(Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.TypeNameParser.GetType(String typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError)
   at Hangfire.Common.TypeHelper.DefaultTypeResolver(String typeName)
   at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob()
   at Hangfire.RecurringJobEntity..ctor(String recurringJobId, IDictionary`2 recurringJob, ITimeZoneResolver timeZoneResolver, DateTime now)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Hangfire.Server.RecurringJobScheduler.ScheduleRecurringJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String recurringJobId, RecurringJobEntity recurringJob, DateTime now)
```

Comment: Seems like the assembly `My.Api` is not present in all the deployments which run as hangfire server. You should check this. What do you mean by : " the dashboard also shows that the app restarts every three minute"

Comment: @jbl My.Api is the main application. So, if it weren't there, heartbeat would not be there too. The second one was happening because the app couldn't get enough ram to run on the servers, we increased the maximum ram amount that the app can use and it seems to be resolved. First error did not go with this, but I did manage to find an extension named `MAMQSql` which does some trick to make the app only see its queue. The error was probably happening because my other app was seeing this app's queue, even though I was starting hangfire with a `queue` name, unique for each app.

Comment: So the error is gone, but this error shouldn't have happened in the first place, where Hangfire says they're scalable and fine for distributed systems. Same schema for multiple apps, and Hangfire needs a third-party extension...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, Hangfire itself does not work great when multiple apps use the same `sql schema`. To solve this problem I used [Hangfire.MAMQSqlExtension](https://github.com/GeXiaoguo/Hangfire.MAMQSqlExtension). It is a third-party extension but the repo says that it is officially recognized by `Hangfire`.
If you are using the same `schema` for multiple apps, you **have to** use this extension in all your apps.

If your apps have different versions alive at the same time (e.g. *production*, *test*, *development*) this app itself does not fully work for **failed jobs**. If a job fails, regular `Hangfire` will not respect it's original queue, hence will move it to the `default` queue. Which will eventually create problems if you app only works with your app's queue or if the default queue is shared. To solve that issue, to force Hangfire to respect the original queue attribute, I used [this](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/pull/502#issuecomment-176744750) solution. Which works great, and you get to name your app's queue depending on your `web.config` or `appsettings.json`.